# Video view in appcelerator titanium

Tags: video, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want a simple "background" view playing a video. With some buttons on top of it.

Is this possible using appcelerator studio?

I DO NOT want a video "player" that opens some native thing. This is meant to be an "ambient" video playing behind the UI components sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try two options here:
natively with Ti.Media.VideoPlayer or using an HTML video tag in a Ti.UI.WebView.

I'd first try using [Ti.Media.VideoPlayer](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer) "as a view [..] added to another view", with properties

fullscreen: false ("On iOS, setting this property to true before the movie player's view is visible has no effect. On Android, this property must be set at creation time"),

autoplay: true,

repeatMode: Titanium.Media.VIDEO_REPEAT_MODE_ONE (iOS/Windows only, to loop the playing video)

mediaControlStyle: Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_NONE.

Hth.

Comment: Yep, that was easy :)

Comment: <VideoPlayer id="videoPlayer" ns="Ti.Media" top="2" url="movie.m4v"
                     height="1500" width="1500" backgroundColor="blue" autoplay="true" top="-400" left="-700" repeatMode="Titanium.Media.VIDEO_REPEAT_MODE_ONE" />